# Java: time delay

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, graphics, timer

I'm trying to paint some points on image. Not all at once but one by one with delay few ms? I tried use timer but it only delays only the start of drawing.
Here is my code, what is wrong?

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        String f = in.nextLine();
                        String[] tokens = f.split(" ");
                        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put(tokens[3],tokens[4]);
                        int x=Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
                        int y=Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);
                        Graphics g1 = bg.getGraphics();
                        g1.drawImage(scaled, x, y, null);
                        g1.dispose();
                        label.repaint();
                    }
                }catch (   FileNotFoundException | NumberFormatException i) {
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, listener);
        timer.start();
```

Comment: 1. use a `ScheduledExecutorService`, this is 2014; 2. why open a new scanner on each loop??

Comment: Because he's in an instructional program and isn't supposed to know or use about ExcecutorServices?

Comment: if you have a loop and you want to slow it down (i.e. delay painting) then you must put the delay code inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All graphics operations should be done on the UI thread. To accomplish this, you should use a SwingTimer

```
class Painter implements ActionListener () {
  int step = 0;
  Timer = this.timer;
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (step > ...) timer.stop();
    switch (step) {
       case 0 : ... ; break;
       case 1 : ... ; break;
    }
    step = step + 1;
  }
}

Timer timer = new Timer(new Painter(), 500);
```

Comment: +1: ^ this. Thank god there are people around here who know that concurrency and timing is not about calling `Thread.sleep()`...

Answer (score 0):

Extract the painting algorithm in a new thread then use `Thread.sleep`:

```
//Pause for 1 seconds
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `while(in.hasNext())` it looks through all the lines in the file, so you only delay it at the start and then it reads all the lines at 1 time.
You could use a `Thread.sleep(500)` beneath `label.repaint();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a delay inbetween each point, you must delay **each** `drawImage` call.

Thus, use something like

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    ...
    g1.drawImage(scaled, x, y, null);
    g1.dispose();
    label.repaint();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```